# Monitoring ActiveMQ Classic JMS client prefetch buffer size with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, activemq-classic

I am using `spring-boot-starter-activemq` to receive messages from ActiveMQ Classic. Recently I have discovered the [prefetch setting](https://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for.html). As I understand when prefetch is more than 0 then ActiveMQ will push multiple messages to one listener and listener will enqueue them locally somehow. I wonder if there's a way to monitor number of messages in a specific consumer's prefetch buffer at any given point in time?

I want to verify that prefetching works correctly and I want to observe how fast prefetch queue gets filled/emptied so that I can manipulate prefetch queue size.

Comment: I want to know number of messages in each consumer. Let's say, I want to verify that prefetching works correctly and I want to observe how fast prefetch queue gets filled/emptied so that I can manipulate prefetch queue size.